# Is there a formula to generate random colors that have the same grayscale value?

Tags: python-3.x, colors, rgb, data-conversion, grayscale

Is there a python 3 function or formula to generate random RGB colors that have the same greyscale value?

For example, 50AA1E, 2B94FF and D16E00, their greyscale value is 808080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the original formula for the RGB->GS conversion, solved for any color component (say, B). Choose R and G randomly and calculate B. Repeat until B is in the permitted range:

```
B = -1
while not (0 <= B <= 255):
    R = randint(0, 255)
    G = randint(0, 255)
    B = int((gray - (R * 0.3 + G * 0.59)) / 0.11)
```

Unless you are seriously unlucky, the loop will terminate.